# Wicket dropdown validation onchange

Tags: validation, wicket, wicket-1.4

I have a dropdown in wicket 1.4 (part of a form) which shows choices for numbers. Now when a number is selected, I change the status of that number to reserved in database using onUpdate method of dropdown.

Now, I want to create a validator which checks whether selected number is already reserved in database or not (by some other parallel process). But this validator should validate only on value change before onUpdate as the number will get reserved in onUpdate method.

So basically what I want to do is to manually invoke validator when I need and prevent it from getting invoked at other times

Or simply, how to make validate and update event work together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just curious; why you would want a validator to do this job when you could potentially add a database call method inside onUpdate itself?

You could still create a reusable method to call it from different places and use it. Validator is something you want to use for format/range kind of validations ( This is my choice - not necessarily best one ) and have business logic validations either in service layer or close to DAO layer if I don't have 'service' layer.

Comment: Agreed, just check the selected number in onUpdate() once, and report an error on the component if it's no longer available.

Comment: I tried to report error for compnent in onUpdate method but it doesn't show up in FeedbackPanel for the form. Also I need error to be there till the value is changed again and disappear once a free number is selected

Comment: I don't necessarily need a validator, but I need to show error at form level and disable submit button if number is already reserved

Answer (score 1):

I think this will never work. As you validate before the update, there is still a chance that the value was changed by another process.

I would use a nice feedback message telling the user that we were unable to update the number because someone else just did it before you.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to do that. I'm first doing a db query in onUpdate method to check if number is free or not before actually reserving it. But how do I report the feedback message to FeedbackPanel of the form which would disable submit button as well

Comment: There are some ways, the easiest is probably making the submit button a Wicket component and call `submitButton.setEnabled(false)` if the number is reserved. You still keep a race condition if you first query and then reserve. You should make the query-and-reserve db method atomic in the database.

Comment: Submit button is part of the form and enabled/disabled by IFormValidator which validates other fields as well. So manually disabling submit button would cause issues. But looks like whatever I have to do, I have to do in onUpdate method itself as suggested by you and others

Comment: Wicket recommends to overwrite  onConfigure method of the component  for enable/visible changes. To achieve that, you could add the submit button to the source component's ajax request target and have onConfigure of submit button to take care of enable/disable. You would still need to take care of race condition as said before.

Comment: Used alternative approach to solve the issue. Now if the number is already reserved, it would be unselectable. User won't get any fancy feedback message but at least they won't be able to select reserved number either. Problem with feedback message was that error reported at component (dropdown) level didn't reach FeedbackPanel defined at form level. And it was coded such that there was no way to report errors manually to FeedbackPanel. It was possible only through validators which I can't use in my scenario

Comment: But directly validating in onUpdate method before reserving number as suggested by all of you was helpful. I'm marking answer given by @Mihir as accepted as he was the first one to answer